# How can I find out where to buy Ripple?

Tags: exchanges, ripple

Hi I just heard about a new alt coin called "Ripple". How can I find out where to buy Ripple?

Comment: Ripple has been around for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ripple is actually not really new but still an interesting coin.

Their website lists several possible exchanges (https://ripple.com/xrp-portal/how-to-buy-xrp/). I have no strong opinion about which of these is most reliable. There are others (https://poloniex.com for example) where you can trade XRP/BTC, too, so if you already have an account at an exchange that you trust that might be the easiest way.